# DOCX: the file is corrupt and cannot be open

Tags: docx, wordml

i am converting Wordml to Docx, and added some default Support files with wordML file,now all the files are Zipped Exactly like DOCX folder structure, while opening the DOCX, i am geting error message like "File Corrupt and cannot open".

Please Help me how to avoid the Error Message.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your Open XML. If you click show details probably it will just say something wrong in line 1.

To find out the error follow these steps:

1. Install  [Open XML package editor power tool for VS 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b/)
2. Then drag and drop your corrupted document and open the document.xml
3. Now select Edit => Advanced => Format Document which will format the
       XML file save the xml.
4. Open the corrupted document again and click show details. This will show the line number where you have the problem.